# Variable only contains certain markers - How to do it in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want that variable `hotels` contain only markers with category "hotel".
I have this code, but it doesn't work (it returns some leaflet error).

```
var hotels = L.geoJson(places, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      if (feature.properties.category == 'hotel'){
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon:hotelIcon});
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Or is there any other better way?

I am only beginner so thank you for your patience.

Comment: I can't help you on that topic, but you should tell more about the "some leaflet error" like stack trace, line numbers, exceptions, etc. It will help people to help you. Error messages are designed for that.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Here is the error: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand t (7 out of range 6). I did not write it because its error in original leaflet.js and I didnt touch that file at all. I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning two different types: a marker or a boolean (false), and Leaflet doesn't know what to do with a boolean.

You should filter your places first to include only the hotels.  Here's an example using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)'s filter function:

```
var hotelPlaces = {
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : _.filter(places.features, function(p) { 
        return p.properties.category == 'hotel';
    })
};

var hotels = L.geoJson(hotelPlaces, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon:hotelIcon});
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you! that will do it!